# In JavaScript, can we import a JS module in the <script></script> tag without loading an external file?

Tags: javascript, import, module

Client side, can we import a JavaScript module in the `<script></script>` tag of a HTML page without loading an external script?

```
<html>
  <head>
  ...
  </head>
  <body>
  ...
    <script>
      document.getElementById('btn').onclick = () => { 
        // Import a JS module here
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well... if you're importing a module, you're loading a file. You can write code within the `<script>` tag though

Comment: You are right, I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `import * as label from "file.js"`. Use the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
  ...
  </head>
  <body>
  ...
    <script>
      document.getElementById('btn').onclick = () => { 
        // Import a JS module here
        import("file.js").then(obj => {
          // Do something with obj
        })
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```